# SELECT unique values from table with multiple columns containing similar data

Tags: mysql, sql, select, distinct

I'm trying to select a list of distinct country codes from a table that has 3 different columns that contain country code data.

**Example**

```
  Raw                                         Desired

+-----------+-----------+-----------+       +-----------+
| country_1 | country_2 | country_3 |       | countries |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+       +-----------+
| GBR       | GBR       | IRL       |       | ARG       |
| DEU       | FRA       | CHE       |       | AUS       |
| CHN       | CHN       | IND       |       | BRA       |
| USA       | CAN       | MEX       |       | CAN       |
| AUS       | JAP       | KOR       |       | CHE       |
| BRA       | ARG       | ARG       |       | CHN       |
| NOR       | SWE       | FIN       |       | DEU       |
| GBR       | FRA       | GBR       |       | FIN       |
| IRL       | IRL       | IRL       |       | FRA       |
+-----------+-----------+-----------+       | GBR       |
                                            | IND       |
                                            | IRL       |
                                            | JAP       |
                                            | KOR       |
                                            | MEX       |
                                            | NOR       |
                                            | SWE       |
                                            | USA       |
                                            +-----------+
```

The closest I've come so far is with a query like:

```
mysql> SELECT
        CONCAT(
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country_1 ORDER BY country_1) FROM tbl),
            ',',
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country_2 ORDER BY country_2) FROM tbl),
            ',',
            (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT country_3 ORDER BY country_3) FROM tbl)
        ) AS countries;

+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
| countries                                                                                       |  
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+  
| AUS,BRA,CHN,DEU,GBR,IRL,NOR,USA,ARG,CAN,CHN,FRA,GBR,IRL,JAP,SWE,ARG,CHE,FIN,GBR,IND,IRL,KOR,MEX |  
+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But as you can see, there are still duplicates and I'm not sure how I could get them into rows either.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Why is `ARG` in your desired result set? isn't it present twice in your table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you want to use group concat. The desired result can be accomplished easily with union, which removes duplicates automatically.

```
SELECT country1 AS countries FROM tab
UNION
SELECT country2 FROM tab
UNION
SELECT country3 FROM tab
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 1):

You get duplicates because you are eliminating duplicates only within each column, not overall.  You probably want something more like this:

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(country)
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT country1 AS country FROM tbl
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT country2 AS country FROM tbl
    UNION
    SELECT DISTINCT country3 AS country FROM tbl
  )
```